# Mathematica doesn't know about the absorption identity?

Tags: simplifying-expressions, special-functions, combinatorics

The well-known binomial absorption identity states that 
$$n\binom{n-1}{k-1} = k \binom{n}{k}$$
However, *Mathematica* gives

```
In[25]:= n Binomial[n - 1, k - 1] == k Binomial[n, k]

Out[25]= n Binomial[n - 1, k - 1] == k Binomial[n, k]
```

What's the problem here?

Comment: You didn't ask Mathematica to do anything. To begin with, try looking at the documentation for FullSimplify and Reduce.

Comment: @Searke This is incorrect, check documentation on `Equal`: returns True if lhs and rhs are identical. So he did ask mathematica to prove symbolic equalities. The fact that Mathematica just does not give answer is because it automatically does not apply expansion and other sets of simplifications.

Comment: As an alternative to `FullSimplify` you can use `FunctionExpand`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
n Binomial[n - 1, k - 1] == k Binomial[n, k] // FullSimplify
```

> True

Comment: I don't get true on my machine.

Comment: @tsuresuregusa. What version are you on?

Comment: I'm in Mac 10.3.1 version

Comment: @tsuresuregusa. Then perhaps something is wrong with your machine. I get `True` on both 10.3.1 and 10.4

Comment: @tsuresuregusa. Well, I'm on Windows 10. I guess that's the difference.

Comment: I get True on my machine, 10.1.0  for Linux x86 (64-bit) (March 24, 2015)